# Django-debug-toolbar shows duplicates in sql queries, how bad is it to have duplicates?

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

django-debug-toolbar showed this message:
392.81 ms (263 queries including 255 duplicates )

how bad is it to have a lot of duplicates, and how can i prevent it?

Thank you

Comment: If `392.81 ms` is fast enough for you and it's not causing a performance problem for your website, don't worry about it. If you want to speed up the page, look at tools like `select_related` and `prefetch_related`. It's not possible to give any more specific advice because you haven't shown any code.